# How can I make flying arbalester constructs with my artificer?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, crafting, flight, constructs

I am playing level 2 artificer and looking to create some Arbalester constructs. I am looking for a way to give them the ability to fly, and I'd like to be able to give them flying by level 4 at the latest. Not for the purpose of recreating the US Airforce, but to allow them to operate outside of melee range. A specific situation I am looking to create is a guardian turret protecting a dungeon room behind us so we don't have to worry as much about having enemies coming up behind us.

Comment: What level is your artificer? When you say "within 2 levels" I imagine you're available to gain features over those next 2 levels (after whatever level you give us), is that right? Or do you mean by level 2?

Comment: Level 2 right now, can snag the feat at level 4. So I can begin building them at level 4.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I've updated your question with that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### At level 4 it is impossible unless you somehow get the Craft Construct feat before level 4.

At 6th character level (with at least 4 levels of artificer) you'll have a feat and access to the craft homunculus class feature (or earlier if you somehow get a feat). With both you can get the feat Improved Homunculus.

**Improved Homunculus** (Magic of Eberron, pg. 49).

Prerequisite: Craft (any) 6 ranks, Craft Construct or craft homunculus class feature.

> (...) If you use the craft homunculus class feature of the artificer class, your homunculus gains natural armor and special abilities based on its current HD, and additional natural armor or special abilities if you later increase its HD.

You improve your homunculus until it reaches 3 HD and he can choose one of the abilities described in table of this feat, one of them is Flyer.

> Gains fly 20 ft. (good) or existing fly speed improves by 20 ft. and maneuverability improves by one category.

To upgrade an Arbalest to 3 HD, you'll spend 4000 gp and 320 XP (You can use your craft reserve here). Your homunculus will be an 3 HD Arbalest with +2 natutal armor and Flyer thanks to your Improved Homunculus feat. The more you upgrade your homunculus, it will get more natural armor and more special abilities.

Comment: Can this be done with just craft construct, without my homunculus? From what I understand you can only get one Homunculus, but there is no limit on crafted constructs. I would like to have a few of these.

Comment: @KaitoX No, you can't. The feat says: "Your **homunculus** gains natural armor and special abilities based on its HD (see chart)." As I emphasized, only your homunculus can be upgraded this way, whichever mean you used to make it.

Comment: Is one limited to one homunculus? The SRD doesn't seem to mention such a limitation? http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/homunculus.htm

Comment: @nijineko While you can use the feat only use the feat to enhance an homunculus, I also couldn't find anywhere limiting someone to one homunculus. If you can afford 10 enhanced homunculi, go for it.

Comment: @aguinaldo The downside of such an approach is that, as a homunculus, when arbalesters die the master takes 2d10 damage. Artificers have d6 hit dice, and if you make a kill-squad of arbalesters that fly in formation and rain bolts down on the target until it dies, they're liable to get fireballed out of existence, quickly dealing more damage to you than you have hp. As awesome as a small fleet of them is, its usually wise to up their HD to get extra features like evasion.

Comment: Don't forget that Arbalesters are Homunculi, which means they are intelligent, and therefore gain feats. In the book they start out with point blank shot, but you can spend their feats however the DM lets you. If you're sold on the flight aspect you can have them take the improved flight feat to let them hover (perfect maneuverability).